# Python bad request in GET but wget and curl work

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to do a get request in python using requests, but I get a 400 bad request error. However, when I do wget or curl on the same url, it works. Here's my code:

```
daily_scoreboard_url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=01/12/2016'
scoreboard_response = requests.get(daily_scoreboard_url)
scoreboard_response.raise_for_status()
```

However, when I try things like

```
curl 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=01/12/2016'
wget 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/scoreboardV2?DayOffset=0&LeagueID=00&gameDate=01/12/2016'
```

it works. I've also tried using a get request for something else from stats.nba.com, and it worked.

```
teamslist_url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats?Conference=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2015-16&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision='
teamslist_response = requests.get(teamslist_url)
teamslist_response.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [give `requests` a user-agent](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

```
>>> headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36'}
>>> scoreboard_response = requests.get(daily_scoreboard_url, headers=headers)
>>> scoreboard_response
<Response [200]>
```

That's the website's fault, not `reuqests`'s. Some websites need a user-agent to check if you're a human or bot/script.

However, we can set the user-agent manually. In the example, that's my Chrome's user-agent.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! But out of curiosity, why did I not need the user-agent for the other url for it to work?

Comment: @birna: As I said, *Some websites need a user-agent to check if you're a human or bot/script.* Seems this website doesn't allow a request without a user-agent. It was set by the owner of the website.